# UITextField clears while scrolling in UITableView - custom cell

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I am trying to save certain values from UITextField however, I am unable to do that because whenever I scroll there is nothing in UITextField. I am using a custom cell. I understand that custom cell has to load in a specific view and for that reason I'm using textFieldDidEndEditing to store values in an array. However, I get the following error message:
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'

Help is much appreciated!! My code is below and I'm quite new in IOS Development.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

  if (indexPath.section == 0) {
    if (indexPath.row == 7) {
      static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"RevButtonCell";

      RevButtonCell *cell = (RevButtonCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

      if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"RevButtonCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [topLevelObjects objectAtIndex:0];
        [cell.revsaveB addTarget:self action:@selector(revaddparse:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        cell.reveditdeleteB.hidden = YES;
        cell.reveditsaveB.hidden = YES;
        cell.revsaveB.hidden = NO;
        cell.revdeleteB.hidden = NO;

      }
      return cell;
    } else {

      static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"TextCell";

      TextCell *cell = (TextCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

      if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TextCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [topLevelObjects objectAtIndex:0];
      }

      cell.detaillabel.text = [revdetailsA objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

      cell.detailtext.placeholder = @"Enter Text";
      cell.detailtext.tag = indexPath.row;
      cell.detailtext.delegate = self;

      if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        cell.detailtext.text = dateS;
      }
      if (indexPath.row == 1) {
        cell.detailtext.text = clientS;
      }
      if (indexPath.row == 2) {
        cell.detailtext.text = productS;
      }
      if (indexPath.row == 3) {
        cell.detailtext.text = amountS;
      }
      if (indexPath.row == 4) {
        cell.detailtext.text = qtyS;
      }
      if (indexPath.row == 5) {
        cell.detailtext.text = taxS;
      }
      if (indexPath.row == 6) {
        cell.detailtext.text = totalS;
      }

      cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

      return cell;
    }
  }
}

- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
  [client insertObject:clientS atIndex:0];
  [product insertObject:productS atIndex:0];
  [date insertObject:dateS atIndex:0];
  [amount insertObject:amountS atIndex:0];
  [qty insertObject:qtyS atIndex:0];
  [tax insertObject:taxS atIndex:0];
  [total insertObject:totalS atIndex:0];
}
```

Comment: see its not compulsory that create array for every textfield value but your every textfield value keep in that textfiled just use bellow code but not insertObject in array..

Answer (score 0):

Initialize the vales of to empty string as

```
clientS = @"";
productS = @"";
dateS = @"";
amountS = @"";
qtyS = @"";
taxS = @"";
totalS = @"";
```

Comment: @megna I don't know how you are saving text to these variables? and the idea of storing in the array at index 0?

Comment: I think you mean @"", not "". One is an NSString literal, while the other is an empty C string (char*).

Comment: @MattLong thanks matt, these days `C#` is on my head and before that it was `Java` so these silly mistakes are common in my codes too. but there I have compiler :)

Answer (score 0):

just use every CellIdentifier are different use `CellIdentifier` like bellow

and also here after use this code ,not required to create array and insert object in it so dont create array just use this code..

```
 NSString *CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cell%d%d",indexPath.section,indexPath.row];
```

use this CellIndentifier insted of another like "TextCell" and "ButtonCell"

i hope this help you...

:)

Comment: You should probably elaborate on your answer. Using a new cell identifier for every cell is a terrible idea for normal dynamic content. In essence it eliminates cell re-use altogether. The reason table views can be so efficient is because you are re-using cells. You use the same identifier to ensure that re-use is actually happening. That being said, in the case of static cells, there's a finite number of cells being used and you could argue it's a simpler way to access the cell you want directly.

Comment: hey @MattLong if above different cellIdentifier is use then here not required to create new array for store value , am i right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I was just suggesting you explain that in your answer. It's a reasonable approach, but only because you are not displaying dynamic content with lots of rows.

Comment: Thanks i created an array in viewdidLoad with empty objects...i.e. placeholder = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"",@"",@"", nil]; then     if (textField.tag == 0) {
        [placeholder replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:textField.text];
    }
    
    if (textField.tag == 1) {
        [placeholder replaceObjectAtIndex:1 withObject:textField.text];
    } Worked!!! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

It looks from your code like you are trying to implement static cells in a table view. What you might want to consider is using a storyboard and creating a table view that supports static table cells just using Interface Builder. This will allow you to eliminate the entire `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method. If you can't use storyboards, then you will have to manage your cells the way you're doing it, but in my book, anytime you can eliminate code, you should.

If you're going to use a storyboard, there a couple things you should know:

- Your view controller in the storyboard needs to be a table view controller
- You set the table Content field to "Static Cells"
- Add the textfields you want to use to each of the cells by dragging them into the cells you add
- Create outlets in your view controller header and then drag connections to them in interface builder

There are some tutorials out there on using table views with static cells. They can be a little long, however, stick with them and you should be able to produce the results you're looking for.

Best regards.